# org.json.JSONObject: Value <?php of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Tags: php, android, json

I am trying to insert data into remote mysql database. The problem I am having is parsing the php file while is located in the remote server. I always get this value php of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject' error.

Here is my php code:

```
<?php
$response = array();
include 'db/connect.php';
include 'function.php';

$inputJSON = file_get_contents('php://input');
$input = json_decode($inputJSON, TRUE);

if(isset($input['user_ID']) && isset($input['submit_your_activity']) && isset($input['how_was_the_activity'])){
    $user_ID = $input['user_ID'];
    $submit_your_activity = $input['submit_your_activity'];
    $how_was_the_activity = $input['how_was_the_activity'];

    if(!userExists($user_ID)){
        $insertQuery = "INSERT INTO userdata(user_ID, submit_your_activity, how_was_the_activity) VALUES (?,?,?)";
        if($stmt = $conn->prepare($insertQuery)){
             $stmt->bind_param("sss",$user_ID,$submit_your_activity,$how_was_the_activity);
             $stmt->execute();
             $response["status"] = 0;
             $response["message"] = "Successful";
             $stmt->close();
        } else {
             $response["status"] = 1;
             $response["message"] = "Failed";
        }
    }
}
else{
    $response["status"] = 2;
    $response["message"] = "Missing mandatory parameters";
}
echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

And here's my java code to connect to php code in remote server. I have used GET method to connect to AWS S3.

```
    private void InsertData(){
        JSONObject request = new JSONObject();
        try{
            request.put(KEY_USER_ID, user_ID);
            request.put(KEY_SUBMIT_YOUR_ACTIVITY, submit_your_activity);
            request.put(KEY_HOW_WAS_YOUR_ACTIVITY, how_was_the_activity);
        }catch (JSONException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, link, request, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                try {
                    if (response.getInt(KEY_STATUS) == 0) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "success", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } else if (response.getInt(KEY_STATUS) == 1) {
                        editText1.setError("User Already Exists");
                        editText1.requestFocus();
                    } else{
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), response.getString(KEY_MESSAGE), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error.getLocalizedMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
        MySingleton.getInstance(this).addToRequestQueue(jsonObjectRequest);
    }
```

The error message is thrown in Response.ErrorListener.

Comment: What is the value you get back from the PHP script.

Comment: @Nigel Ren I think the reply I get from PHP script is the same error message that says cannot be convertable to jsonObject.